# Customise Table of Contents header and heading

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

When using `\tableofcontents` my TOC gets generated like this:
[image: Table of Contents]

Why does the word Contents appear twice and what is the easiest way of changing it to only show the header and not the big heading. How can I change the actual word to something like "Table of Contents", and also switch it to a different font like Times New Roman? I am using `\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}` in this instance and the current font seems to be associated with that.

Although when using

```
\dottedcontents{chapter}[2.5em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
```

it comes out like this:

[image: ToC 2]

Which looks a little better around the contents, but still with the main heading and header in the same fashion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
\KOMAoptions{headings=small}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\mdseries}
```

to decrease the font size and change the font family/series for all chapter/section headings consistently. To adjust the content of the chapter heading preceding the table of contents, redefine `\contentsname`, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
```

By default, the first page of a chapter (and hence of the table of contents) does not include a running headline. I don't know why you get one. Ensure that you haven't put a

```
\thispagestyle{headings}
```

after `\tableofcontents`. Moreover, check that you haven't redefined `\chapterpagestyle` as

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the title of the table of contents following the instructions here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fixnam

You can probably also change the font that way, but that is not recommended as according to the LaTeX philosophy the font should be determined via your document class consistently for section titles throughout the document. (As far as I know, scrbook is part of KOMA-Script - its documentation will probably contain some pointers on customising fonts etc.)

Regarding your first question - are you sure the first, smaller "Contents" isn't a header line for the page (i.e. not generated by \tableofcontents)?

Comment: Thanks Dan. The smaller Contents dropped away when I removed \usepackage{tocloft} from the preamble. Although I would rather want to keep the smaller friendlier header and get rid of the ugly big bold heading.

Comment: Have a look at "Options for Font Selection" and "Options Affecting the Table of Contents" in the KOMA-Script manual - does that not allow you to do what you want?

Comment: The following produce a nicer look: 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\Large\hfill\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill}

Comment: I found this in the KOMA-Script manual. \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{← descriptionlabel}} But it is not clear to me how to actually change the font for the TOC heading.

Comment: I don't use KOMA-Script myself, so I can't help you with the details. However, a quick look suggests the font size selection for headers is described in manual section 3.1.4 and the actual font selection is in section 3.2.1 and 3.6.2. The latter seems to discuss pretty much what you want. (Another possibility would be to use a different document class, considering the small page size.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer can be found in tocloft package -- http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/tocloft.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: `tocloft` is designed to work with the standard classes. Hence, it does not work well with KOMA.